# How to create custom edit menu and remove the default edit menu which is shown in pdfview for iOS 16

Tags: highlight, pdfkit, ios16, uimenucontroller, pdfview

1. I am not getting any action callback on the default `Highlight` edit menu, when selecting the text and pressing the `Highlight` edit menu, where do we get the callback of this edit menu?
2. Also I am trying to remove this default edit menu and trying to add a set of new edit menus but some of the default edit menu is not getting removed. So how can we achieve this
3. Do we need to use `UIEditMenuIntraction` to add a new edit menu since in iOS 16 `UIMenuController` is deprecated, if yes then how to implement it on the text selection in pdfview.
4. For iOS 16 I have tried to override the default edit menus using `UIMenuBuilder` and added a few new edit menus as a sibling, but unable to remove the default edit menu ex-(`Highlight').

```
- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder{
    if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
        [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuLookup];
        [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuReplace];
        [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuShare];
        [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuFormat];
        // Add new .textStyle action
        UIAction *testMenuItem = [UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Test" image:nil identifier:nil handler:^(UIAction *action){
            NSLog(@"action callback");
        }];
        [builder replaceChildrenOfMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuStandardEdit fromChildrenBlock:^NSArray<UIMenuElement *> * _Nonnull(NSArray<UIMenuElement *> * _Nonnull existingChildren) {
            NSMutableArray *children = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:existingChildren];
            [children addObject:testMenuItem];
            return children;
        }];
    }
    [super buildMenuWithBuilder:builder];
}
```

2. Also tried `canPerformAction` method to get the action callback of default Highlight edit menus and tried to the removed default edit menus by returning `No` but no luck.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
  BOOL can = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
  
  return NO;
}
```